# Failure to fetch http://somesite.com could not resolve somesite.com

Tags: networking, server, dns

I am changing my Ubuntu server from dhcp to static ip address. I haved added the following to the /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 120.120.120.120
    netmask 225.225.254.0
    gateway 120.120.121.120
    dns-nameservers 120.120.10.10
```

I have also restarted the server. I can access the server from port 443 and I can use the server to ping the nameserver and also one of googles on

```
ping 74.125.225.180
```

but if I try and ping www.google.com I get the error

```
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

Can anyone help? Do I NEED a second nameserver address that is common to most setups?

Edit - added results of ifconfig eth0

here is a screenshot of terminal as vSphere wont allow copy paste

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40655046/Capture.PNG

Comment: have you activated the interface `eth0` ?

Comment: good question, if I run `sudo ifconfig eth0 120.120.120.120 netmask 225.225.254.0 up` this works but if I run `sudo ifup eth0` i get the error `RTNETLINK answers: File exists Failed to bring up eth0` I guess this is my problem?

Answer (score 1):

> I am changing my Ubuntu server from dhcp to static ip address.

That's OK if you know what you're doing and if the network you're in doesn't interfere (for example if you chose a static IP that's already taken).

Please post and append it to your question

- the output of `sudo ifconfig eth0`
- the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`
- the output of `dìg www.google.com`

> Do I NEED a second nameserver address that is common to most setups?

Not really, but it's always handy to have a second one in case the first one goes down. There's no harm in specifying a second DNS there.

Comment: I dont fully know what I am doing but I was issued the IP by the IT department and given settings that should work. I have added the results in my first post. There is no output from resolv.conf as its an empty file that says its overwritten and should not be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try running 
`sudo ifconfig eth0 down` 
`sudo service networking restart`

and provide `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

**UPDATE**
As we see, you have problems with resolv.conf file. Try this: 
`sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf` 
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`

Info from this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1836144&p=12520090#post12520090

Comment: tried this, same problems

Comment: there is nothing in resolv.conf apart from a note saying not to manually edit this file. Thanks for trying

Comment: Look at this comment http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1836144&p=12520090#post12520090

Comment: Amazing this worked! Post this as the answer and I will mark it as correct